# Lumia 550 charging issues

Tags: charging, lumia-550

My L550 can last an impressive 4 days before dying, but I could only discover this once. This phone took 8 hours to charge 18% overnight. It charges so slowly that if I am just checking the time on it every ten minutes or so whilst it's charging, it will continue to lose charge.

I have tried other chargers but there is little difference. Plugging the phone into my computer doesn't help either as it still just loses charge.

Do I need to replace the battery? Or find some magical super-charger? All the reviews of the phone I found talked about the battery charging "in a few hours" - hopefully "few" here didn't mean 40.

Comment: Are perhaps you running an insider preview build? Those are known for causing battery issues sometimes.

Comment: Same issue when I got my 550, slow charging but drains very fast. Had the OS updated which solved a lot of issues.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when i used micromax USB cable to connect with PC and samsung charger to charge my phone. Use only MS/Nokia branded usb cables and wall bricks. they're faster in charging our phone, others wont work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Charging it normally will make it charge very slowly. However, plugging it in when it is below 10% battery will have it charged completely within half an hour. I expect this is just weird behaviour from lithium ion batteries.

Comment: That's pretty weird!